# <script defer> and $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

According to http://caniuse.com/script-defer, most browsers support the `script` tag's `defer` attribute.

I would like to know if scripts specified by `<script defer src="...">` get executed before or after jQuery's `$(document).ready()`? Are the major, modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc.) consistent in the order of execution or does it vary?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Based on this <del>fiddle</del> I have to say jQuery's `$(document).ready()` executes **after** a script declared with `defer`. I tested it with Firefox and Chrome, and both had the same behavior independently of the sequence of the scripts.

I guess behavior on other browsers might change based on their implementation, so it's always uncertain.

**EDIT**: As it turns out, the `defer` attribute should be used with an external javascript file. I edited the fiddle to show this, apparently with the same results.

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RNEZH/15/

Comment: Same result in Opera, but isn't the defer attribute only interesting for external scripts? I don't think <script defer="defer">alert("a")</script> does make sense.

Comment: @Bergi, external or not, the `defer` attribute is for deferring the script's execution. What do you think doesn't make sense?

Comment: @Usman, I'm sorry, as it turns out I really was wrong. Thanks for pointing it out. I should change the test.

Comment: @TomS: [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-defer) says "The defer and async attributes must not be specified if the src attribute is not present." It's about whether to continue parsing the document or not, instead of waiting with execution.

Comment: @Bergi, that makes sense. I though defer was only for deferring the script's execution.

Comment: I got the same results with your fiddle in IE6 so IE6+ should work too.

Comment: This presume's you have deferred jQuery, right? I think the fiddle does a synchronous jQuery load, then your defer, the the ready().

Comment: I tested that fiddle with a 2mb script (that line + 2mb of comments) and it worked as expected.

Comment: -1 This 100% won't work if you `defer` jQuery as the inline script tag will be executed before jQuery is loaded and `$` will not be defined.

Comment: I would've agreed with you prior to today, but I've found that if you add latency to a script (using fiddler for example to make a script take 2 seconds) that the jquery ready event occurs before the defer script loads (only tested on Chrome).  It seems you can use `$(window).on("load", initFunc)` which will run `initFunc` after deferred scripts.  This isn't ideal unfortunately since I believe that window on load event fires after images are loaded, etc...

Answer (score 12):

The defer attribute has a good [write-up and analysis](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/defer/). **Also** See the comments to the post for additional info on how `defer` has been re-defined in HTML5.

My conclusion: `defer` is too browser dependent to count on. Therefore use the jQuery doc ready technique.

To put it another way, an important reason for jQuery is to cover browser inconsistencies. Defer is another such inconsistency that should be avoided for well written pages.

Comment: I don't see any comments anywhere that has info on how defer has been redefined in HTML5.

Answer (score 7):

Simply, `script` should be executed before `$(document).ready()` whether `defer` is used or not and  almost all major browsers [support](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) `defer`.

But for being safe side I encourage you to use both `$(document).ready()` and `defer`.
So why `defer`? Because it helps page appear quickly (as external script is loaded parallel) and a really important factor in Google's page speed tool, a good detail can be found here http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html#DeferLoadingJS

Comment: This information is not correct, the document ready is being called even if the jquery with defer param is not loaded yet

Answer (score 6):

To defer inline javscript you can use type="module" which then makes $(document).ready() redundant.

```
<script type="module">alert('defered inline js')</script>
```

Because type="module" implies defer scripts will execute in order with other deferred scripts.

See can I use 96% browser support in May 2023.
https://caniuse.com/es6-module

Comment: Works for me with Firefox and jQuery 3.2.1 - thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I've observed a race condition in pre-3.0 versions of jQuery, on Chrome (88.0.4324.96).  I don't see this on Safari nor Firefox.

```html
<body>
  <script defer src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script defer src="test.js"></script>
</body>
```

test.js:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  console.log('jQuery version', $().jquery);
  console.log(a);
});

const a = 'OK';
```

This fails with `Cannot access 'a' before initialization` about 10% of the time in my experience.

Once I upgrade to jQuery 3, I'm not able to reproduce.  As this is a race condition, I can't be 100% sure, but it seems pretty conclusive to me.