# Add defer tag to a existing script tag

Tags: jquery, ready

I have a few tags script on the page. For a particular script tag I want to add "defer" tag using jQuery.

```
<script src="/path/to/JS" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For reasons limited by CMS, I cant make that change when adding the script.Although I can run jquery on page ready/load.

Is there a way to that on page load using Jquery to read src and add defer tag?

```
<script src="/path/to/JS" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
```

Comment: Aside from what I wrote in my answer, if you're aware of a reason why the CMS you're using is more of a hindrance than a tool, you might want to consider alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You can get script after page load with jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $.getScript('/path/to/JS');
});
```

or if you want to insert DOM obj:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');

    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = '/path/to/JS';

    $('body').append(s);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're entirely aware of what defer does. jQuery's ready event triggers is fired **after** the point of time scripts with the defer attribute would be executed at

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8638598/6252717