# ReferenceError: xxx is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im strugling with wierd error on my eshop. It dont always show, I even didnt know about it, because on my PC it dont shows, but I made debug function that send all javascript errors to my email.
I get ReferenceError: po_zaladowaniu_strony is not defined
po_zaladowaniu_strony is function that should be run as last after page load, it sets everything up etc.
I head i have (as a first scripts):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/po_zaladowaniu.js?v=<?php echo date(U); ?>" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/strona.js?v=<?php echo date(U); ?>" ></script>
```

then before closing body tag i have:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js' defer></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazyload/1.9.1/jquery.lazyload.min.js" defer></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="/js/lightbox.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function(){
        <!--  ODPALA Skrypty potrzebne po załadowaniu strony -->
        po_zaladowaniu_strony("<?php echo $_SESSION["sesja_id"] ?>","<?php echo $_SESSION["typ"]; ?>");
    });
</script>
```

po_zaladowaniu_strony function have its subfunctions in po_zaladowaniu.js and strona.js that are declared as first in html. So, why is that error occuring some times?

Comment: Depending on the browser, `defer` can load your script after your doc.ready - remove the `defer` to be safe.  Decent modern browsers cache *parsed* scripts anyway, so those will likely already be in the browser cached, already parsed, reducing the need for `defer`.  More info on SO with a link https://stackoverflow.com/a/8638597/2181514

Comment: Ok, deleted defer tag, now we wait and see :) thanks for tip

Comment: Please share more details. Also, please explain how this error is related to PHP

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with `defer`. Thanks to [freedomn-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181514/freedomn-m) who pointed out, in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65845582/referenceerror-xxx-is-not-defined/65887817#comment116419907_65845582) that:

> Depending on the browser, `defer` can load your script after your doc.ready - remove the `defer` to be safe. Decent modern browsers cache *parsed* scripts anyway, so those will likely already be in the browser cached, already parsed, reducing the need for `defer`. More info on SO with a link [stackoverflow.com/a/8638597/2181514](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8638597/2181514)